# wp_mail recipient array not sending?

Tags: email, wp-mail

I am using wp_mail to send an email to multiple recipients.

my mail function looks like this:

```
wp_mail($group_emails, 'my subject', 'my message', $headers);
```

`$group_emails` is an array of email address's and gets outputed like this:

```
$group_emails = Array ( [0] => ceri@test.com [1] => craigj@test.com [2] => danyob@test.com [3] => geoffh@test.com [4] => ianc@test.com [5] => mark.butcher@test.com [6] => mickh@test.com [7] => mike@test.com [8] => stephd@test.com [9] => stuartj@test.com )
```

For some reason the email does not get sent to the above emails? If i remove the multiple recipients and just put a single email address, it works fine!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

You can consider any of the following.

1.My **preferred**:

```
foreach($group_emails as $email_address)
{
   wp_mail($email_address, 'my subject', 'my message', $headers);
}
```

2.Another way

Define the array as follows.

```
$group_emails = array('ceri@test.com', 'craigj@test.com', 'danyob@test.com', 'geoffh@test.com', 'ianc@test.com', 'mark.butcher@test.com', 'mickh@test.com', 'mike@test.com', 'stephd@test.com', 'stuartj@test.com' );
```

And then try your regular procedure:

```
wp_mail($group_emails, 'my subject', 'my message', $headers);
```

I am not sure about the second way. But the first way will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to what @Rohit has said, you can also send multiple recipients as a `comma-separated string`.

From the **[`Codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Parameters)**

```
<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>
```

> Parameters
>
> $to
>       (string or array) (required) The intended recipient(s). Multiple recipients may be specified using an array or a comma-separated string.
>
> Default: None

Comment: But it does say "string or array" so array should work!