# wp_mail is not sending email if I pass an array of emails

Tags: wp-mail

On publish `event` CPT, I want to send emails to every participant set in the custom meta boxes.

When I pass `array` as email addresses it is not sending email

```
wp_mail( $employee_emails, $subject, $message );
```

but if I use string then it sends the emails. I don't understand what is wrong with the code or `wp_mail`

```
wp_mail( 'me@emailid.com', $subject, $message );
```

## My Code

```
function ac_send_event_notification( $ID, $post ) {

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $ID ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // employees details
    $employees  = rwmb_meta( 'ac_event_employees', [], $ID );
    $positions  = rwmb_meta( 'ac_event_positions', [], $ID );
    $operations = rwmb_meta( 'ac_event_operations', [], $ID );

    // event details
    $operation_user_ids = [];
    if ( ! empty( $operations ) ) {
        foreach ( $operations as $operation ) {
            $operation_user_ids[] = ac_get_event_participants_ids_by_operation( $operation );
        }
    }
    $position_user_ids = [];
    if ( ! empty( $positions ) ) {
        foreach ( $positions as $position ) {
            $position_user_ids[] = ac_get_event_participants_ids_by_position( $position );
        }
    }
    $operation_ids = array_reduce( $operation_user_ids, 'array_merge', [] );
    $position_ids  = array_reduce( $position_user_ids, 'array_merge', [] );

    sort( $employees );
    sort( $operation_ids );
    sort( $position_ids );

    $employee_ids_to_notify = array_unique( array_merge( $employees, $operation_ids, $position_ids ) );
    sort( $employee_ids_to_notify );

    // get employees email ids
    if ( ! empty( $employee_ids_to_notify ) ) {
        foreach ( $employee_ids_to_notify as $employee ) {
            $employee_emails[] = get_the_author_meta( 'email', $employee );
        }
    }

    // Sending email to the participants

    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name   = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );

    $subject = sprintf( 'New Event Created by %s', $name );
    $message = "Hello,\n\n";
    $message .= "There is a new event created by {$name}.\n\n";
    $message .= "Check out all details with the following link.\n\n";
    $message .= get_the_permalink( $ID );

    wp_mail( $employee_emails, $subject, $message );

}
add_action( 'publish_event', 'ac_send_event_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the email to more than one user, then you can write a loop.

```
foreach ($employee_emails as $email) {
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message );
}
```

This will loop through all the email addresses in the array and send the email to each one of them.

### UPDATE

You can store your email addresses into a single string, separated by commas:

```
$employee_emails = '';
foreach ( $employee_ids_to_notify as $employee ) {
    $employee_emails .= get_the_author_meta( 'email', $employee ).', ';
}
```

Then you can pass it as a single string to `wp_mail`.

Comment: Yes, I can run the loop. However, my question is even [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#parameters) allow to pass an array or multiple recipients than why it is not working?

Comment: BTW, I have tried foreach loop and it is not sending email.

Comment: @pixelngrain Try and dump your email address array by `var_dump`. There is most likely an issue in your array.

Comment: I have already tried that. See here `array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "me@myemailid.com" }` I have also tried `implode()` but no luck. :(

Comment: @pixelngrain I updated the answer for you.

Comment: Let me try this too.

Comment: Another bad surprise, when I add as a string (as you suggested), it is sending mail but with no recipient. Getting mad with this simple issue.

Comment: @pixelngrain How did you find out it's sending the emails if no one received it? This shouldn't be happening. Maybe some plugin is interfering. You can try the native PHP `mail()` function and see if WordPress is causing the issue.

Comment: I am using [WP Mail Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-logging/) Plugin for that. It shows all details about email.

Comment: @pixelngrain [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/127530/94498) question might help you. If not, then probably some plugin or the theme is interfering.

Comment: Just a thought, I am on localhost using WP Mail SMTP plugin. Do you think so that could be the issue? But I believe, that should not as it is sending mail but just when I use array or pass variable to the `$to` I am also not sure if SMTP will work with PHP native `mail()`

Comment: @pixelngrain Unfortunately questions about plugins are off-topic here, since they require knowledge about the plugin too. But, anything that comes between WordPress and sending the email has the potential to mess something up. You can try disabling all the plugins and try again.